# Sequence of Prime ideals in a Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the $d$ variable polynomial ring $R=k[x_{1},\cdots,x_{d}]$ show that
$0, x_{1}R, (x_{1},x_{2})R, \cdots , (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{d})R$ is a strictly increasing sequence of prime ideals and there is no longer such chain.  how do I prove this claim?

Well, I am thinking that for this problem this result may be helpful: for a ring, $R$, to be Noetherian, one formulation dictates that any ascending chain of ideals in $R$ terminates. But I just can't get going with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard proof uses Noether normalization. For a superb introduction to (Krull) dimension of rings see Chapter 8, "Introduction to dimension theory" in Eisenbud's "[Commutative algebra, with a view toward algebraic geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387942696)", esp. Section 8.2.1, and for the proof see Section 13.1.

Comment: Is this a theorem or a problem from that book.

Comment: @Chandru1: It is a theorem. Further, the introductory Chapter 8 on dimension theory is by far the best in any textbook, so I highly recommend that you consult that first for motivation.

Answer (score 3):

Bill is right that the most standard proof uses Noether normalization.  Another proof exploiting the fact that $R$ is a Hilbert-Jacobson ring can be found in Section 8.2 of

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)

The exposition here follows Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings*.

Comment: Thanks Pete, there is an $R$ above your post,i wonder why that has come.